# How to keep a constant ip address?

Tags: ip

I am from south Asia, using internet with ip address something like, `180.234.23.24`. But each time I restart computer, the last two place are randomly changing. I am trying to keep a constant ip address each time, tried `Changed Adapter Setting` and a tool from sourceforge `FastIPChangerV1.8`, but it didn't work. Buying VPN or using proxy server isn't my intention. Besides contacting with the internet service provider, is there any other way to get a constant ip address?

P.S. Please let me know this is the right place for asking this question, not by giving down vote.

Comment: Many ISPs will allocate a static IP address, if you purchase a business class service, rather than household consumer-grade service.  You cannot achieve this by reconfiguring anything on your home machine or network.   Alternatively, you can use a dynamic DNS service to use a fixed domain and hostname, while keeping it synchronized with changes to the IP address assigned by your ISP.

Comment: Thanks Jim,that answers a lot. I spent around 4 hours on it, and nothing could do on nothing.